# In MySQL, Is it bad practice to apply "AS" [tablename] to a subquery (or derived table)? If so, Why?

Tags: mysql, select, syntax, subquery, alias

## Avoiding "AS" for named tables in Subquery?

I received multiple working answers to a previous MySQL [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44702597/7470217) about a year ago.

I'll grab a snippet from two of the answers and mark them up rather than copying the whole query and take up space. (Unless you need me to)

Both answers worked.

### Answer 1

> The first answer used **`AS`** preceding the named table alias,**`AS highestcost`** and **`AS lowestcost`**...

```
...
FROM   vendor
   inner join vendorparts on vendor.id = vendorparts.vendorid
   inner join part on vendorparts.partid = part.id
   inner join product on product.partid = part.id
   INNER JOIN (SELECT vendorparts.partid,
                      Max(vendorparts.lastcost) AS Highestcost
               FROM   vendorparts
               GROUP  BY vendorparts.partid) AS highestcost
           ON part.id = highestcost.partid
   INNER JOIN (SELECT vendorparts.partid,
                      Min(vendorparts.lastcost) AS Lowestcost
               FROM   vendorparts
               GROUP  BY vendorparts.partid) AS lowestcost
           ON part.id = lowestcost.partid
WHERE  vendorparts.lastcost <> 0
```

### Answer 2

> The second answer did not use **`AS`**, instead they just added some extra spacing between the closing parenthesis and its alias. They also renamed the tables **`t1`** and **`t2`** so to avoid ambiguity with any column names which I will definitely start doing this since it's much less clutter.

```
...
FROM  vendor 
INNER JOIN vendorparts on vendor.id = vendorparts.vendorid 
INNER JOIN part on vendorparts.partid = part.id and 
INNER JOIN product on product.partid = part.id
INNER JOIN (SELECT vendorparts.partid,
                        Max(vendorparts.lastcost) AS Highestcost
                FROM   vendorparts
                GROUP  BY vendorparts.partid)  t1
            ON part.id = t1.partid
INNER JOIN (SELECT vendorparts.partid,
                        Min(vendorparts.lastcost) AS Lowestcost
                FROM   vendorparts
                GROUP  BY vendorparts.partid)  t2
            ON part.id = t2.partid
WHERE  vendorparts.lastcost <> 0
```

### Why?

> Both answers worked, Second answer specified to "***Avoid using***" **`AS`**, but Why?

I've been using **`AS`** for derived table names for awhile and haven't ran into any issues. And MySQL themselves show the use of **`AS`** on their documentation of derived tables which is [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html).

Does it come down to personal preference? Better performance? If it matters, the second answer was provided by a user with 80,000+ reputation with only 1 question. So I'm kind of assuming he's right. Maybe I'm reading the MySQL documentation improperly.

Comment: Most databases I have used allow aliases with or without `AS`, and I would assume that this is part of the ANSI standard.  Use whichever you prefer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen which do you prefer?

Comment: I don't use it (most of the time), because I find it bloats the query with something which doesn't need to be there.  I'm curious what @GordonLinoff would have to say here, so I'm upvoting your question.

Comment: I never use AS. It's redundant and interrupts my scanning of the query. But this is surely personal preference. It can have no significant impact on the optimizer, although if you run EXPLAIN EXTENDED my query, followed by SHOW WARNINGS, it always adds them back in, along with those pesky backticks